# php resize image then crop image problem

Tags: php, gd, crop, image-resizing

I want to reduce a picture size from 600px * 500px to 60px * 50px size, then crop it become 50px *50px. I have two groups of codes, 1 is to reduce the size of image, other 1 is to crop the image. The problem is they works separately, how to combine this two groups of codes to make them work together? Below is my codes :

```
<?php

//codes of group A - Reduce the size of image from 600px * 500px to 60px * 50px   
    $save2 = "images/users/" . $image_name_2; //This is the new file you saving
    list($width2, $height2) = getimagesize($file) ; 
    $modwidth2 = 50; 
    $diff2 = $width2 / $modwidth2;
    $modheight2 = $height2 / $diff2; 
    $tn2 = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth2, $modheight2) ; 
    $image2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
    imagecopyresampled($tn2, $image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth2, $modheight2, $width2, $height2) ; 
    imagejpeg($tn2, $save2, 100) ; 



//codes of group B - Crop the image from 60px * 50px to 50px * 50px 
    $save3 = "images/users/" . $image_name_3;  
    list($width3, $height3) = getimagesize($file) ; 
    $modwidth3 = 60;  
    $diff3 = $width3 / $modwidth3;
    $modheight3 = $height3 / $diff3; 

    $left = 0; 
    $top = 0;

    $cropwidth = 50; //thumb size
    $cropheight = 50;

    $tn3 = imagecreatetruecolor($cropwidth, $cropheight) ; 
    $image3 = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
    imagecopyresampled($tn3, $image3, 0, 0, $left, $top, $cropwidth, $cropheight, $modwidth3, $modheight3) ; 
    imagejpeg($tn3, $save3, 100) ; //save the cropped image
?>
```

As you can see from 2 groups of codes above, 1st group resize the pic then save it to a folder. 2nd group of codes crop the pic then save it into the folder too. My question is ... After 1st group of codes resize the picture, is it necessary to save it into folder before I can crop it? If it is necessary, then I need to write new lines of codes to retrieve the resized pic from the folder for 2nd group of codes to crop it? If it is not necessary, after resizing the pic, how do I pass the pic to 2nd group of codes to crop it?

Comment: And where do you resize the picture? Can you mention the line?

Comment: hi, i have update my question by adding the resize picture codes. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Let me clarify: you have picture with resolution e.g. 900x600, and you want to resize the image, so that the smaller side will be 50 (in this case resize the image to 75x50) and then crop it to 50x50. Don't you?

Comment: @Arman P, yes, you are right.

Comment: Use this class: https://github.com/qaribhaider/php-image-resize , 1- resize image to exact width height 2- resize using crop method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are @zac1987.
Full **PHP** code generating square thumbnail of desired size without stretching image. The code supports both png and jpg/jpeg image extensions. Simply change settings part to desired one. You can copy paste the code and test it on your web server.

```
<?php

    // SETTINGS
    $image_name = 'file.jpg';    // Full path and image name with extension
    $thumb_name = 'thumbnail';   // Generated thumbnail name without extension
    $thumb_side = 100;           // Desired thumbnail side size
    // END OF SETTINGS

    $image_extension = explode('.', $image_name); // I assume that images are named only following 'imagename.ext' pattern

    if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/', $image_extension[1])) {
        $src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_name);
        $image_extension = 'jpg';
    } else if (preg_match('/png/', $image_extension[1])) {
        $src_image = imagecreatefrompng($image_name);
        $image_extension = 'png';
    }

    $src_width = imageSX($src_image);   // Width of the original image
    $src_height = imageSY($src_image);  // Height of the original image

    $min_side = min($src_width, $src_height);

    /*********** If you need this part uncomment it
    $ratio = $min_side / $thumb_width;
    $new_width = floor($src_width / $ratio);
    $new_height = floor($src_height / $ratio);
    **********************************************/    

    $dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_side, $thumb_side);

    imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_side, $thumb_side, $min_side, $min_side);

    switch ($image_extension)
    {
        case 'jpg':
            imagejpeg($dst_image, $thumb_name . '.jpg', 100);
            break;
        case 'png':
            imagepng($dst_image, $thumb_name . '.jpg', 100);
            break;
    }

    imagedestroy($src_image);
    imagedestroy($dst_image);

?>
```

Comment: @zac1987 You're welcome, meanwhile to crop from other coordinates (not Left: 0, Top: 0) - simply edit 3rd and 4th zeros in `imagecopyresampled`.

Comment: yes, I did assign the coordination onto your code. if($src_width > $src_height){ $top=0; $left=70;}elseif ($src_width < $src_height){$top=70; $left=0;} Thanks again for your helping hand.

Answer (score 1):

```
$modwidth3 = 500;  //I resize the picture width to smaller as 60px.
$diff3 = $width3 / $modwidth3;
$modheight3 = $height3 / $diff3;  //I resize the picture height to smaller.

$left = 1; //getting the left and top coordinate
$top = 1;

$cropwidth = 50; //thumb size
$cropheight = 50;

imagecopyresampled($tn3, $image3, 0, 0, $left, $top, $cropwidth, $cropheight, $modwidth3, $modheight3) ;
```

`$modwidth3` and `$modheight3` need to correspond to the width and height of the image you want to crop. Also `$top` and `$left` should match the top left coordinate of the area you want to crop. If the original image is 600x500 px and you want to resize and crop to 50x50, you should set $top to 0 and $left to 50 (px). Both $modwidth and $modheight should be set to 500. That keeps the full height of the original image and cuts away 50px from the left hand side and 50px from the right hand side. The remaining 500px is cropped to 50px.

Comment: the original image size is not fix, maybe it is 800px * 1200px, so your concept about cutting 50px of both sides won't work for that. Furthermore, if I do as what you said like "$modwidth and $modheight should be set to 500", then the image will look stretched since the original image is 500px * 600px.

Comment: True, the code is not complete and you'll probably find errors in the calculations. I did not test the code. The text below the code should however give you a lot of information on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

link to a blog article i wrote about how to resize any size image to any arbitrary size. includes options for letterboxing and crop-to-fit.

http://www.spotlesswebdesign.com/blog.php?id=1